# Como achar números primos num determinado intervalo?

Tags: c++

Preciso de uma ajuda nesse programa, na parte do for. Seguinte, preciso imprimir os números primos dentro desse intervalo A e B determinado pelo usuário, o problema é que o programa só imprimi um numero dentro desse intervalo.E tbm mostrar se tem ou não número primo dentro do intervalo. Agradeço caso alguem posso ajudar.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
int a, b, div=0;
printf("Digite o numero a:\n");
scanf("%d",&a);
if (a>=0 && a<=100){
    printf("Numero a esta entre 0 e 100\n",a);
}else{
    printf("Nao esta entre 0 e 100, digite novamente:\n", a);
    while(a>100){
        printf("Numero ivalido, digite novamente: \n");
        scanf("%d", &a);

    }
}
printf("Digite o numero b:\n");
scanf("%d",&b);
if (b>=0 && b<=100){
    printf("Numero b esta entre 0 e 100\n",b);

}else{
    printf("Nao estao entre 0 e 100, digite novamente:\n",b);
    while(b>100){
        printf("Numero invalido, digite novamente: \n");
        scanf("%d",&b);

    }

}
for(int i=a+1;i<b;i++){
    if(div%i==0){
        div++;
        printf("%d\n",i);

    }

}
if(div==2){
    printf("Sem numeros primos no intervalo");
}
```

}

Comment: A parte de achar os primos está quase toda por fazer, acabando por ter bastante código mas quase nenhum focando o problema. E assim fica dificil ajudar sem fazer o código todo..

Comment: Bom, eu queria saber como fazer essa parte do intervalo, pro programa imprimir os numeros primos nesse intervalo digitado pelo usuário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um pequeno exemplo funcional para você analisar, lembrando que os números primos so podem ser divididos por ele mesmo e por um, por isso é necessário mais de uma estrutura de repetição no código, qualquer duvida me contate :)

```
int primo=0;
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int tem_primo = 0;

printf("Numeros primos::.\n");

for(int i = a; i<=b; i++){

  //Inicia o verificador sempre como zero
  primo=0;

  for (int x = 1; x <=i; x++) {

    if(i % x == 0){
      primo++;
    }

  }
  if(primo==2){

    //Mostra na tela os numeros primos um a um
    printf("%d; ", i);
    tem_primo = 1;
  }
}

//Verifica se há primos no intervalo
if(tem_primo == 0){
  printf("\nNao possui primos no intervalo");
}
```